# google api dict has no attribute authorize

Tags: python, discord, google-sheets-api

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DarthyBot.py", line 49, in <module>
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 288, in build
    adc_key_path=adc_key_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 540, in build_from_document
    http = _auth.authorized_http(credentials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_auth.py", line 119, in authorized_http
    return credentials.authorize(build_http())
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'authorize'
```

trying to get a discord bot written in python to grab some info out of a google sheets document and post it into chat. i'm trying to use the googlepapi and gspread but something's wrong and i've not got a clue.

my code is as follows (posted the chunks that have to deal with the sheets stuff, left out my google service account api keys ect)

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from jokeapi import Jokes
import gspread
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

creedentials={has the appropriate stuff in it}

sh_id = "order_order_and_progress"
gc = gspread.service_account_from_dict(creedentials)
sh = gc.open(sh_id)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creedentials)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()

def get_progress(rescue_ranges, sh_id):
  result_shit = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=sh_id, range=rescue_ranges).execute()
  value_dental = result_shit.get('values', [])
  return(value_dental)
```

and there's also the catch, but its not even getting that far

```
if message.content.startswith('$progress'):
    beans = get_gif("working")
    beaned = beans["results"][dummy]["url"]
#    listed = get_progress(rescue_ranges, sh_id)
    await (message.channel.send(TERG + ", Here\'s how things are looking \nhttp://alinktosomewhere.neat \n" + beaned))
```

Comment: Can you provide your current script for replicating your issue?

Comment: updated, if i need to post more i will, but the entire bot was working including that $progress command, before i started to work on making it just pull the spreadsheet values directly

Comment: Thank you for replying. Where does the error `'dict' object has no attribute 'authorize' ` occurs in your script?

Comment: the traceback is all i can find and that's where it says it, at the end of that tracestack

Comment: its saying its this line `service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creedentials)`

Comment: Than you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About `its saying its this line service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creedentials)`, when I saw your script, `creedentials` of `service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creedentials)` is `creedentials={has the appropriate stuff in it}`. If `{has the appropriate stuff in it}` is the JSON data of the service account including `private_key`, `client_email` and so on, unfortunately, that value cannot be directly used for `service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creedentials)`. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

When you want to use `service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creedentials)` with the service account and `creedentials={has the appropriate stuff in it}` is the JSON data of the service account including `private_key`, `client_email` and so on, how about the following modification? In this case, please also set the scopes.

#### Modified script 1:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

creedentials = {has the appropriate stuff in it}

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(creedentials, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
```

#### Modified script 2:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

creedentials = {has the appropriate stuff in it}

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(creedentials, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
```

#### Note:

- You can use both samples. So please chose one of them.
- In this modification, it's a simple sample script for using `service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)` with the JSON data of the service account including `private_key`, `client_email` and so on. So please modify it for your actual situation.
- And, this sample script uses the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`. If you want to use other scopes, please add them.

#### References:

- [oauth2client.service_account module](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html)
- [google.oauth2.service_account module](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html)

Comment: thank you that helped! i can at least print the range i asked for now! now to move onto turning it into a nice list lol. thanks again

Comment: @helmet648 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand by your cooperation. Thank you, too.